# Shuffle and only show a certain item in a PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get shuffle and only 19 items in a `for each` loop. I used `shuffle()` and `if (++$i == 19) {break;}`, but the problem is one time it returns 12 items, one time 13, and another time 14. What did I do wrong?

Here is the code to check:

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    shuffle($children);
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        if ($child['name_total'] > 0) {
            ?>
            <li>
            <?php echo ($child['filter_id'] == 2 ? "<span class='Verified'><i class='fa fa-check-circle'></i></span>" : ""); ?>
                <div class="CatImg"><a title="<?php echo $child['name']; ?>" href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"><img alt="<?php echo $child['name']; ?>" src="<?php echo $child['thumb']; ?>"/></a></div>
                <a title="<?php echo $child['name']; ?>" href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"><?php echo $child['name']; ?><span class="Total"><?php echo $child['name_total']; ?></span></a>
            </li>
        <?php
        }
        if (++$i == 19) {
            break;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: All the values satisfy `$child['name_total'] > 0` condition? I guess `++$i == 19` check should be inside the first `if`.

Comment: @SougataBose yeah, db got more than 30 items with this condition.

Comment: What is the initial value of `$i`?

Comment: If some element have less than 1 they wont be displayed but `$i` will be incremented for them as well.

Comment: @topher it was  before that line that i've copied here. updated.

Comment: How many items do you want returned?

Comment: You means you want to shuffle array but not remove array elements right ?

Comment: print_r($children); post array values here

Comment: Just FYI using == as a loop terminator test is risky because your variable will only == the terminating condition for 1 loop.  You're much better off checking if it's exceeded a value so then there's no risk of it not exiting the loop because the value wasn't tested on an iteration where it equalled the terminating value.  In this particular case it shouldn't be a disaster because you're using foreach which terminates at the end of the array anyway, but it's really not a good habit to be getting into and you will eventually get stuck in an infinite loop if you keep doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase $i only when a result has been printed. Check the value before starting a new foreach loop.

```
 <?php
$i = 0;
shuffle($children);
foreach ($children as $child) {
    if ($child['name_total'] > 0) {
        ?>
        <li>
        <?php echo ($child['filter_id'] == 2 ? "<span class='Verified'><i class='fa fa-check-circle'></i></span>" : ""); ?>
            <div class="CatImg"><a title="<?php echo $child['name']; ?>" href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"><img alt="<?php echo $child['name']; ?>" src="<?php echo $child['thumb']; ?>"/></a></div>
            <a title="<?php echo $child['name']; ?>" href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"><?php echo $child['name']; ?><span class="Total"><?php echo $child['name_total']; ?></span></a>
        </li>
    <?php
     $i++;
    }
    if ($i == 19) {
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to shuffle array,

Use this function,

```
function shuffle_assoc(&$array) {
    $keys = array_keys($array);

    shuffle($keys);

    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $new[$key] = $array[$key];
    }

    $array = $new;

    return true;
}
$i = 0;
shuffle_assoc($children);

foreach ($children as $child) {
    if ($child['name_total'] > 0) {
        ?>
        <li>
        <?php echo ($child['filter_id'] == 2 ? "<span class='Verified'><i class='fa fa-check-circle'></i></span>" : ""); ?>
            <div class="CatImg"><a title="<?php echo $child['name']; ?>" href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"><img alt="<?php echo $child['name']; ?>" src="<?php echo $child['thumb']; ?>"/></a></div>
            <a title="<?php echo $child['name']; ?>" href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"><?php echo $child['name']; ?><span class="Total"><?php echo $child['name_total']; ?></span></a>
        </li>
    <?php
    }
    if (++$i == 19) {
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

I hope this will help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

A simplified version of your code

```
foreach ($children as $child) {

    if ($child['name_total'] > 0) {
        // display stuff
    }

    if (++$i == 19) {
        break;
    }
}
```

So `$i` is incremented every time, even if nothing is displayed.  If `$child['name_total']` is 0, nothing will be displayed - but `$i` is still incremented.

If you want 19 items displayed, you need to only increment `$i` when something is actually displayed:

```
foreach ($children as $child) {

    if ($child['name_total'] > 0) {
        // display stuff

        if (++$i == 19) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following.

```
 <?php 
$counter = 0;

shuffle($children); 

foreach ($children as $child) 
{

    if ($counter < 18)
    {
        break;
    }

    if($child['name_total'] > 0)
    { 
    $counter++;
?>
    <li>
    <?php echo ($child['filter_id'] == 2 ? "<span class='Verified'><i class='fa fa-check-circle'></i></span>" : "");?>
    <div class="CatImg"><a title="<?php echo $child['name']; ?>" href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"><img alt="<?php echo $child['name']; ?>" src="<?php echo $child['thumb']; ?>"/></a></div>
    <a title="<?php echo $child['name']; ?>" href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"><?php echo $child['name']; ?><span class="Total"><?php echo $child['name_total']; ?></span></a>
    </li>
<?php  
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your loop will terminate immediately.